# Why am I getting a 404 for django_rq admin screen?

Tags: django

I have django-rq set up and running (jobs are queued, I can run `manage.py rqworker`) but I cannot seem to get the admin screen working - I consistently get a 404 for the /admin/django_rq url.

I have django-extensions installed, and the `show_urls` commands shows that the URL is registered:

```
$ python manage.py show_urls
...
/admin/django_rq/ django_rq.views.stats rq_home
/admin/django_rq/queues/<queue_index>/ django_rq.views.jobs rq_jobs
/admin/django_rq/queues/<queue_index>/<job_id>/ django_rq.views.job_detail rq_job_detail
/admin/django_rq/queues/<queue_index>/<job_id>/delete/ django_rq.views.delete_job rq_delete_job
...
```

I am logged in as someone who is a staff member, so the `@staff_member_required` decorator on the `stats` view should be working.

Comment: Did you forget the trailing slash? It's `/admin/django_rq/`, not `/admin/django_rq`.

Comment: `[09/Feb/2013 13:25:40] "GET /admin/django_rq/ HTTP/1.0" 404 1635`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(r'^admin/django_rq/', include('django_rq.urls'))
```

must be before

```
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls))
```

Answer (score 1):

I've updated the installation instructions in django-rq's README.rst to drop the "admin" prefix from django-rq's URL pattern so Hugo's issue shouldn't happen again.